# Need help fixing Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I am getting an error in js.do that reads

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable:exports on line 22

Line 22 reads

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
```

When I test it in the service simulator on developer.amazon, it responds

> the remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid

What does this mean, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't know Alexa, but shouldn't that be `module.exports`?

Comment: Every tutorial and guide I've seen on Alexa uses exports.handler

Comment: Well, then the error is most likely in the 21 lines before `exports.handler =` that you didn't post.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/U7rRfbeC here's the full code

Comment: Unsurprisingly, `exports` isn't defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: Okay so how can i fix it, because the source code from the tutorial i followed never defined exports

Comment: If you want a better chance of someone answering this, please paste in the previous 20 lines, don't just link to them, and also link to the tutorial you are following and preferably quote any relevant bits.

Answer (score 0):

I have also come into this issue when creating Alexa Skills previously.

I have found that after I enter the utterance on the text simulator (and get the error); if I copy the headers and switch the the JSON simulator and paste the request in there now it will work.

If you have the green tick your service is working and this is a bug with Amazon Service Simulator.